Did Not pickle '_thread.RLock' object
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[33], line 3
1 file_path="vector_index.pkl"
2 with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
----> 3     pickle.dump(vectorindex_openai, f)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
enter image description here
Store the infor in variable dataset and after i question returen the info

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object google that and you'll learn

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
